# Tab number, instead of number of windows

Tags: vim

[image: Default tabline]

Above is default tabline, I want that instead of number of windows I ll see there index of tab, in the above example '1 quickfix.txt | 2 tabpage.txt' to simply call `[index]gt` to go to target page. **Is it possible to acquire default string for tab, for example '2 quicklix.txt' then swap first digit with tabnumber to get '1 quickfix.txt'?**
P.s.
I don't want to write scripts the way vim is suggesting, see `:help tagline`, in the sense, that there many features like cropping and showing if file is modified, which I like and don't want to write them from scratch. What I want is to get default string for tab and modify it the way I explained earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> P.s. I don't want to write scripts the way vim is suggesting, see `:help tagline`, in the sense, that there many features like cropping and showing if file is modified, which I like and don't want to write them from scratch.

As discussed earlier, your goal is impossible to achieve without at least a little bit of scripting.

You don't have to write anything "from scratch", though. The snippets generously provided to you under `:help setting-tabline` and `:help setting-guitablabel` cover a lot of ground so you only have to copy them to your `vimrc` and modify them to suit your needs.